# What is the use or the significance of the ornamental gold cross in Castlevania: Order of Ecclesia?

Tags: castlevania-order-of-ecclesia

There is an ornamental gold cross in the church at the end of Oblivion Ridge with a directional-pad shape in the center and two arrows on either side on the horizontal bars.  Are you supposed to do something near it to activate it?

Comment: Oooh, this is the tattoo castlevania, isn't it? Oy, it's been 2 years since I played that game.

Comment: The same cross was used in Castlevania PoR for a quest too.

Comment: Seems like they reuse a lot of stuff.  :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the only thing to do is to destroy the lower portion of the wall, as it conceals a hermit ring.

Here's a youtube video  of someone breaking the wall:

Comment: Yeah, watched a few more, Everyone just walked right past it without comment. e.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXApedZMJ2Q&feature=related Darn.  It looked like it could have led to something interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, a later quest with the old lady has you sketch the inside of the church, so the cross sseems to act as a marker for that.

Comment: Iv'e done all the old ladys drawing tests nothing was mentioned so far

Comment: I can confirm this. The final sketch is that cross at the church.